# Nullable class members to represent mathematical unknowns

Tags: c#, nullable

Let's say I have a class `Point`:

```
class Point
{
    public double? x, y;
}
```

In order to indicate that either `x` or `y` is an unknown, I've made their types nullable.

Now, when using these values in mathematical expressions, it's inconvenient to have to cast their values to double each time. I.e. `Math.Sin(p.x)` will yield a compile time error; you must cast it instead: `Math.Sin((double)p.x)`.

My approach for getting around the casting issue is to have wrapper read only properties which perform the casting:

```
class Point
{
    public double? x, y;

    public double X { get { if (x != null) return (double)x; else throw new Exception(); } }
    public double Y { get { if (y != null) return (double)y; else throw new Exception(); } }
}
```

Is this a good approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `Value` property of `Nullable`:

```
Math.Sin(p.x.Value)
```

Or

```
public double X { get { return x.Value; } }
```

This will throw an exception if the value has not been set, so is equivalent to your code.

Regarding the relative merits of the approaches:

IMO the property based approach shields consumers from the implementation detail that `x` is internally stored as a `Nullable` to represent unknown-ness. This would be my preference if consumers are only expected to deal with 'known' values. If however, consumers are expected to cater for a situation where `x` remains 'unknown' then exposing a `Nullable` property would be the way to go (and any consumers can check using the `HasValue` property of `Nullable`).

Answer (score 2):

I'm personally not a big fan of the generic exception that is thrown when trying to access to a property (in particular the generic `InvalidOperationException` thrown when accessing `.Value` of `Nullable<T>` when `HasValue == false`). I would instead expose boolean properties that specify if the values are defined:

It would be part of the contract that the developer checks for members validity before trying to access to properties:

```
public class Point
{
    private double? x;
    private double? y;

    public bool IsXDefined { get { return this.x.HasValue; } }

    public bool IsYDefined { get { return this.y.HasValue; } }

    // Returns an undefined value (default(double)) in case X is not defined
    // This is a part of the contract that X is valid if, and only if IsXDefined is true.
    public double X { get { return x ?? default(double); } }

    public double Y { get { return y ?? default(double); } }
}

Point p = new ...
if (p.IsXDefined)
{
    double zz = p.X ....
}
```

---

Actually there are different approaches for the same goal, but the important thing is that the developer is aware of what the code actually does. An exception is a fine way to let the developer knows the property he's trying to read isn't in the good state.

In the above code, the documentation for the X property would say "*the X coordinate of the Point, if defined. To ensure `X` is a valid value, check that `IsXDefined` returns true before trying to access to this property*".

The `PointCoordinateNotDefinedException` is also great:

```
public double X
{
    get
    {
        if (this.IsXDefined)
        {
            return this.x.Value;
        }

        throw new PointCoordinateNotDefinedException();
    }
}
```

Same here for the *contract*: the documentation for the X property would say "*Can throw `PointCoordinateNotDefinedException` exception if the coordinate is not defined. Check that `IsXDefined` returns true before trying to access to this property*".

Both are OK for me, maybe the exception is better you're right, as it would crash the application if the value is unspecified (which would prevent the application to run with incorrect values (harder to debug than looking in the stacktrace to see what thrown an exception)).

But still, **I don't think trying to access to properties until they throw an exception** (while catching those exception) is a good idea. I prefer testing the `IsXDefined` boolean before accessing to the property.

Comment: I am also not a fan of the `InvalidOperationException` thrown when nullables have no value, but returning the default value instead will hide bugs in careless consumers of your class.  I would rather throw an exception, and if the `InvalidOperationException` is not specific enough, create a `PointCoordinateNotDefinedException` or some such thing.  I presume you considered such an approach, so I am curious why you prefer the default value approach.

Comment: you could just do public double X { get { return x.HasValue ? x : throw new PointCoordinateNotDefinedException(); } }

Comment: @ken2k I completely agree with you on catching the exception: clients should call `IsXDefined` rather than using try-catch.  It just occurred to me that the class as defined is not thread safe, so in a multithreaded program, the check would still not guarantee that the exception won't be thrown.  The value could be set to null between calling `IsXDefined` and `X`.  That's another (more compelling) reason to throw an exception, since the default-value approach could lead to a client considering `0.0` to be a valid value precisely because they *have* checked `IsXDefined` before reading `X`!

Comment: by the way I already upvoted your answer when I posted the first comment, so don't think I'm snubbing your edit if your vote total doesn't increase :)